# What are the admin/user default credentials for JBoss BRMS 6 on EAP 6.1.0

Tags: authentication, jboss

I have setup JBoss 6.1.1 EAP with JBoss BRMS 6 for EAP 6.1.1 installed over. I am getting the new business-central app;s login page, but none of the credentials seem to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Try to locate file `brms-users.properties` inside your server, there should be default user and password in plaintext.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did search earlier, infact found that file's reference in BRMS 5.3.1's user guide. But i did not find the file. Just a note again, I am using BRMS 6.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the add-user script to create users and then use the same